# Trying to implement forward rendering in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, lighting, opentk

I'm working on implementing forward rendering in my 2D engine, as far as I'm aware everything should be set up correctly, I've ran into some issues earlier but I'm sure I've fixed those at this point.

So what I'm doing to achieve this (May or may not be the correct way of going about this) is that I'm rendering the object first with ambient light (Which works), and then for each light affecting the object, I render it once again using a different shader for point lights. I've set that shader to only output the color red atm, but nothing shows up apart from the first render of the object (The one with the ambient light).

Here are some pieces of my code.

**Rendering of the object**

```
        shader.Use();

        shader.SetUniform("_Model", transform.Model);
        shader.SetUniform("_Color", color.Normalized.ToVector3());
        shader.SetUniform("_Diffuse", texture.ArrayPos);

        VertexAttributePointer.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 5, (System.IntPtr)0);
        VertexAttributePointer.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 5, (System.IntPtr)(3 * sizeof(float)));

        //Render sprite
        quad.VAO.Bind();

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);

        //Transparency
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.One, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

        //Draw object
        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Quads, 4, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        //Forward rendering
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.One, BlendingFactorDest.One);

        GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Equal);
        GL.DepthMask(false);

        Shader pointLightShader = Shader.GetShader("Forward-Point");
        if (pointLightShader != null)
        {
            pointLightShader.Use();
            shader.SetUniform("_Model", transform.Model);
            shader.SetUniform("_Color", color.Normalized.ToVector3());
            shader.SetUniform("_Diffuse", texture.ArrayPos);

            foreach (Light l in Light.lights)
            {
                pointLightShader.SetUniform("_PointLight.position", new Vector3(l.position.X, l.position.Y, 0));
                pointLightShader.SetUniform("_PointLight.color", l.color.Normalized.ToVector3());

                GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Quads, 4, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
            }
        }

        GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal);
        GL.DepthMask(true);
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);

        quad.VAO.Unbind();

        texture.Unbind();
```

**Forward-Point fragment shader**

*Note that it is temporarily set to only output red, which should globally tint all objects if it works.*

```
#version 330 core

struct Light {
    vec3 position;  
    vec3 color;
}; 

uniform vec3 _CameraPos;
uniform vec3 _Color;
uniform sampler2D _Diffuse;
uniform Light _PointLight;

out vec4 color;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec3 FragPos;

void main()
{
    vec4 diffuse = texture(_Diffuse, TexCoords);

    float distance = length(_PointLight.position - FragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0;

    vec3 finalLight = _PointLight.color * attenuation;

    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What happen if you change `glDepthFunc` to always passes?

Comment: Tried that earlier, same result. It doesn't seem to be a depth issue. I even tried not drawing to the depth buffer at all so it shouldn't be that. @Greffin28

Comment: If i were you, i would leave `glDepthFunc` to always passes and then do debugging, such as trying to render just 1 light. Or test it to render not from the light variables (Input the variables manually). If that renders, then bit by bit try to reconstruct the code.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, I just changed it to Equal before I posted this since it technically is my actual value for it. I've tried changing around a lot of values while having it set to always pass with no luck, so I'm thinking it might be another issue.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to mention you in my comment. @Greffin28

Is there anything else you can think of that might be causing the problem?

Comment: no no, i just got up and reach my phone. what happen if you use it to draw a full screen quad? so many debugging to do, lol. we should discuss this on chat or something though.

Comment: @Greffin28 I'm currently rendering objects over all of the screenspace already that are using the same shader, should produce the same effect as a full screen quad I think?

How do we go about discussing it on chat?

Comment: those objects didn't show up? maybe check your vertex, see if all matrices is initialized correctly. check your light objects too

Comment: @Greffin28 Oh no they do show up, it's just the second pass not working correctly. Basically everything under the "Forward Rendering" comment.

Comment: Check if _pointLightShader_ is not null (in debugger) and check if you have added any lights to _Light.lights_.

Comment: @Shot Forgot to say that the loop does run, so both of those are already tested.

Comment: How do you create GL context?

Comment: @Shot Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Lym - how do you create OpenGL Window/Surface that you want to use later to draw something there?

Comment: What happens if you disable the ambient pass, and just use the point lights? Also, you should really be doing this all in the same pass. Pass your lights in as a uniform array and loop in the shader. Draw calls are more expensive than looping in the shader.)

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, you're not checking for errors. Do that.

Comment: One more thing: you're drawing the quad in **exactly the same place** over and over again. Though that **should** just cause the last thing drawn to be on top of everything else, I'd try offsetting the quad along Z and see what happens. You can just add a small value to the vertex Z in the vertex shader, or adjust your model matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short list of things to check:

- Does Forward-Point shader compiles successfully?
- Does point light shader program (Program Object) links successfully?
- Do you call ***`glClear`***`(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` before rendering?
- Have you enabled depth test (***`glEnable`***`(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`)?

Comment: Yes to all of those, sadly.

Comment: @Lym do you bind variable named _texture_ somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

One of the big benefits of forward rendering is that you can do all your lights in one shader. Switching programs is very expensive so you should not be switching programs for each rendering of objects. At the least you should do all of the rendering for all objects with the first shader THEN switch to the point light shader.

Here is a tutorial illustrating this idea:

http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Lighting/Multiple-lights

My guess is that you are doing something incorrect with the quad draw however, and that is the current error. Probably the wrong space is being used for the position or something like that. There are too many possible errors to know for sure without spending a lot of time on it though.